# Two different chat interfaces

Tags: support, chat

I use a MacBook and access Stack Exchange sites with a Stack Overflow app that I created with [FluidApp](https://fluidapp.com/).

I notice that when I'm in chat, I can't hit <kbd>enter</kbd> to send a message. Further, the page layout is different from when I open chat in say, Chrome. Also, enhancements such as autocompletion of usernames and hover buttons such as 'star', 'quote', etc.

Initially, I considered that this might be due to disabling JavaScript, but my preferences indicate that I am not doing so.

Does anyone have any thoughts on what's going on and how to fix this?

Technical Specs:

- Max OSX 10.9 Mavericks
- FluidApp 1.7.2

Screenshot (FluidApp):

[image: chat messages stretch across the screen]

Screenshot (Chrome):

[image: chat messages are only part of screen, with a room sidebar]

Comment: Would be useful if we could see the specifics of the app you designed. Else we are just shooting in the dark.

Comment: @InbarRose: it was created with fluidapp, which is a site-specific browser. Very straighforward. There's nothing technically relevant that I did there

Comment: How about a screenshot then?

Comment: @InbarRose: Good idea. Updated

Comment: That is the mobile chat layout you're getting

Comment: Isn't this more a bug in fluidapp?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is because you are using the mobile chat layout. Press the "menu" button at the bottom and press the "full site" button.

Comment: I don't see a `full site` button on any menu and the help menu doesn't show any such thing in the search. Requesting additional guidance

Comment: @inspectorG4dget it's in the bottom left corner of your screenshot

Comment: LOL! I thought you meant menu in fluidapp

Comment: @inspectorG4dget For that I'd have used "menu" instead of "menu button". I thought I had put the location; somehow the edit wasn't saved.